# Django keeps generating new migration about user's email

Tags: python, django, authentication, database-migration

The django application I am currently working on behave strangly. Each time I run the `makemigration` command, it create a new migration for the `auth` application:

```
Migrations for 'auth':
  0007_auto_20160407_1426.py:
    - Alter field email on user
```

Do you know what I can try to solve this issue ?

Migration file:

```
# venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0007_auto_20160407_1426.py

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(help_text='Required, 255 characters or fewer. Only letters, numbers, and @, ., +, -, or _ characters.', unique=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='email address'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Hard to say without the model and the migration code.

Comment: What part of the model would be useful ? (it's really long)

Comment: The field that is changed by the migration?

Comment: Updated, I added the migration file.

Comment: Nothing dynamic in there, so I guess you just did a change to that field.

Comment: Well what I don't understand is that I changed nothing in my models and the  same migrations keeps happening (if I run 4 time "make migration" and "migrate" it creates new one each time ... )

Comment: You still have not posted your model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108528/discussion-between-nobe4-and-klaus-d).